# CoffeeScript: HTTPS Post to API, handle response

Tags: javascript, post, coffeescript, http-post, hubot

I'm new to CoffeeScript/JavaScript, but writing a script for Hubot to talk to my Ansible Tower API in Coffee. Below is my code so far:

```
module.exports = (robot) ->
robot.respond /deploy zabbix agent (.*)/i, (res) ->
    host = res.match[1]

    https = require 'https'

    authbody = JSON.stringify({
        username: "awx.api",
        password: "example"
    })

    authrequest = new https.ClientRequest({
        hostname: "awx.example.co.uk",
        port: 443,
        path: "/api/v2/authtoken/",
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Content-Length": Buffer.byteLength(body)
        }
    })

    authrequest.end(authbody)

    body = JSON.stringify({
        limit: "#{host}"
    })

    request = new https.ClientRequest({
        hostname: "awx.example.co.uk",
        port: 443,
        path: "/api/v2/job_templates/35/launch/",
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Content-Length": Buffer.byteLength(body)
        }
    })

    request.end(body)

    res.reply "Deploying zabbix agent to #{host}"
```

In the **authrequest** section, I post my username and password to the API and it should return in the response JSON in the following format:

```
{
"token": "8f17825cf08a7efea124f2638f3896f6637f8745",
"expires": "2013-09-05T21:46:35.729Z"
}
```

My questions is how I store the token to use as my authentication in the later requests.

Answer (score 0):

You can store it in localStorage like so:

```
localStorage.setItem("token", "8f17825cf08a7efea124f2638f3896f6637f8745",);
```

and the get it when you make a request and insert in your header

```
const token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token'));

request = new https.ClientRequest({
    hostname: "awx.example.co.uk",
    port: 443,
    path: "/api/v2/job_templates/35/launch/",
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Content-Length": Buffer.byteLength(body),
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
    }
})
request.on('response', function (response) {
  response.on('data', function (chunk) {
       let json = JSON.parse(chunk);
       localStorage.setItem("token", json['token']);
  });
});
```

Comment: How do I grab those from the response though of the authrequest bit?